# Load Two from Two separate firebase databases into a tableview swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase, swift3

I am building a very simple app where people click a button and it records the time they clicked the button (checked-in) using firebase database. I have no problem **storing** the data of the people who checked in and then displaying the data of the people who checked in with all the appropriate information. I have included a picture to show what I already have displayed in my TableViewController.
[image: This is what my TableView shows right now]

I don't want to show only the users that have checked in I also want to show the users who have not yet checked in.

I will now share a photo of how my firebase database is setup to store every single user.

[image: How my database is setup to store all users]

Here is a view of the entire database that shows the users and the users who have already checked in with there name and timestamp

[image: Entire database]

I will also include the code from my UITableViewController so everyone can see how I am showing only the people who are already checked in.

```
 import Firebase

struct checkInStruct {

let userName : String!
let hour : String!
let minutes : String!

}

class checkInDaysTableViewController: UITableViewController {


//Variables
var lastChildNameSegue = ""

var posts = [checkInStruct]()
let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

    let userID = user?.uid

    databaseRef.child("users").child("\(userID!)").child("checkins").child("\(lastChildNameSegue)").queryOrderedByKey().observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in


        let userNameSnapValue = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        let userName = userNameSnapValue?["userName"] as? String


        let hourSnapValue = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        let hour = hourSnapValue?["hour"] as? String

        let minutesValue = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        let minutes = minutesValue?["minutes"] as? String

        print(userName!)
        print(hour!)
        print(minutes!)

        self.posts.insert(checkInStruct(userName: userName, hour: hour, minutes: minutes) , at: 0)
        self.tableView.reloadData()


    })

}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return posts.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")

    let userName = posts[indexPath.row].userName
    let hour = posts[indexPath.row].hour
    var minute = posts[indexPath.row].minutes

    let minuteInt = Int(minute!)

    if(minuteInt! >= 0 && minuteInt! <= 9){
        let minuteWithZero = "0\(minuteInt!)"
        minute = minuteWithZero
    }

    let label1 = cell?.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel
    label1.text = "\(userName!)"

    let label2 = cell?.viewWithTag(2) as! UILabel
    label2.text = "Checked In At \(hour!):\(minute!)"

    return cell!
}



}
```

**What would I need to do in order to load the data from all the users and highlight anyone in red who hasn't yet checked in?**

Comment: If i am getting this right, You want to make an app where the status of all the users 'Check_Ins' is visible to each and every one of your users, right? Also update your question with the actual JSON in textual format not a snapshot of it.

Comment: Basically the checkin list I want to display the people who have checked in and the time. And in the same list I want to show the people who have not yet checked it @Dravidian

Comment: I can't help you until i see your entire(RELEVANT - ARCHITECTURE) JSON tree..

Comment: hello @Dravidian I have uploaded a photo that shows the entire tree hopefully you can help now

Answer (score 0):

I think you should design you database like this.

`root -> users`

```
"users": [
    "{id_user_A}": {
        "name": A,
        "checkedin": [
            "{id_checkedin_1}": {
               ...
             },
            "{id_checkedin_2}": {
               ...
             } 
        ]
    },
    "{id_user_B}": {
        "name": B,
        "checkedin": []
     }
]
```

And get all users, check each user with `checkedin` property to know which user checked in.

Comment: yes but how would I handle multiple check-ins and the time value for all the days?

Comment: So, let `checkedin` is array value

Comment: can you think of anyway to do this without storing it under the user.

Comment: Hello @luan-tran I have updated my post hopefully you can help now.

Answer (score 0):

You gotta change your JSON tree structure

```
Users : {

   userID_1 : {
      userName : John Joe,
      checkInID : UNIQUE_ID_1; 
         },  

   userID_2 : {
      userName : Meghan,
      checkInID : UNIQUE_ID_2; 
         } , 

   userID_3 : {
      userName : Maria,
      checkInID : UNIQUE_ID_3; 
         } 

      },

CheckIn_List : {

     UNIQUE_ID_1 : true;  // This id has checked in
     UNIQUE_ID_2 : true;  // This id has checked in
     UNIQUE_ID_3 : false; // This id has not yet checked in..

          },
CheckIn_User_Info : {

     UNIQUE_ID_1 : {
      userName : John Joe,
      time : //time; 
         }  

   UNIQUE_ID_2 : {
      userName : Meghan,
      time : //time; 
         }  

   UNIQUE_ID_3 : {
      userName : Maria,
      time : //time; 
         } 
      }
```

Procedure you wanna follow :-

- If you are authenticating your every user of the app, you already have an user_ID then all you gotta worry about is the checkin id which you can use as the `Firebase server Timestamp`.

  ```
  var checkinID = FIRServerValue.timestamp()
  ```
- If you are not authenticating your user; skip the first part you still need the ***checkinID***
- Append these to security rules

  ```
   "Users" : {

       ".write" : "auth != null && auth.uid === $uid",  // Will allow only the user to make any change within its node and no-one else
       ".read": "auth != null && auth.uid === $uid"
       },

    "CheckIn_User_Info" : {
        ".write" : "auth != null", 
        ".read" : "auth != null"
       },
     "CheckIn_List": {
        ".write" : "auth != null", 
        ".read" : "auth != null"
       }
  ```
- I have used a different unique id for checkIn id because in future you might wanna add some more details of your user that you might wanna hide from other users, so this solves that problem

Comment: Just so we are clear all those users are under one account so I don't need to worry about auth. And there is no way we can use the JSON tree I already have? @Dravidian